# Text Field Content not taking full space after increasing its size

Tags: html, css

I have created two html elements, one text input and one textarea.

There was a need to increase the size of the field just for proper design. But when I enter text in the field it does not take full space.

[image: Text only partially filling the input]

My Code For Text Field:

```
<label for="exampleForm2">Task Title</label>
<input type="text" id="exampleForm2" class="form-control" style="padding-right: 155px">
```

My Code for text area:

```
<label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Task Desciption</label>
<textarea class="form-control rounded-0" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="8" style="padding-right: 160px;" name="taskdetails"></textarea>
```

Comment: It's your `padding-right`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution after some research myself.

Just added size and cols attribute to both the fields

Tasktitle Field:

```
<label for="tasktitle">Task Title</label>
<input type="text" id="tasktitle" class="form-control" size="50" name="tasktitle">
```

Taskdetails Field:

```
    <label for="taskdetails">Task Desciption</label>
<textarea class="form-control rounded-0" id="taskdetails" rows="8"  name="taskdetails" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do not** use `padding-right` to `textarea` **set `width` if you want it be bigge**r

```css
textarea{
width:300px
}
```

```html
<label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Task Desciption</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control rounded-0" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="8"  name="taskdetails"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seams that the **"padding-right: 160px"**; is your problem.
Remove it and use **"width"** instead